# Pandas using RegEx with a list in lxml

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

I am trying to scrape all the URLs from a website that meet a certain criterion. My code is so far as follows:

```
  import pandas as pd
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  import lxml.html
  links = []
  connection = urlopen("http://www.open.ac.uk/courses/modules")
  dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
  for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'): 
      links.append(link)
```

This is getting me the URLs in a list. However, I only want the ones that end with /[some letters][3 numbers]. I have the following expression which works at www.regex101.com:

```
  \/[a-z]*[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Ideally I would like to amend the scrape so it only returns the required information. How can I use the expression on the list to filter it?

I have found a few things that kind of answer my question but nothing that is the same as my problem.

An example of the data I am getting is

```
 /courses/modules/tm352
 /courses/modules/a332
 /courses/modules/ke322
 /courses/modules/e318
 /postgraduate
 #int-site
 http://www.open.ac.uk/contact/
 http://www2.open.ac.uk/tutors/help/who-to-contact
 http://www.open.ac.uk/about/employment/
 http://www.open.ac.uk/about/main/management/policies-and-
 statements/website-accessibility-open-university
 http://www.open.ac.uk/wales/cy
```

So of that the first 4 lines match what I want the rest do not match.

Comment: I suggest adding an example (or some examples) of the URLs you're trying to filter to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(links)
df[0] = df[0].str.extract('(.+[A-z]+\d\d\d$)', expand=False)
df.loc[df[0].notnull()]
```

Comment: Thanks not exactly what I needed but was able to amend it to get what I needed.